How does MOND explain ‘low dark matter’ galaxies?
MOND attempts to solve the rotation curve problem of galaxies by modifying the law of gravitation. However, there are galaxies (notably NGC 1277) where the rotation curves do more-or-less agree with what you would expect from GR.
Using dark matter this is easily explainable by saying that the galaxy simply has very little dark matter (I am aware that there are problems with explaining how this came to be). How could something like this possibly be explained by MOND? Or, more generally, what is the MONDian counterpart to differing amounts of dark matter in galaxies?
(I don’t believe that my personal stance on MOND is relevant to the question, but in case someone thinks it is: I find MOND quite unconvincing. I believe this is also the mainstream opinion of astrophysicists.)

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123661, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581277

Last I saw the two most common ways are:

Modify the theory. This is how (extensions of) MOND explain the cosmic microwave background.
Keep the theory, but say it is non-visible ordinary matter causing the effects. This is what Milgrom wrote about the Bullet Cluster.

One can also:

Say the observations are wrong. (I've not seen papers on this, but I didn't do a search.)

